# How can I count deceleration on mysql query time by the number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, time, row-number

I want to know how MySQL runs a query on a table. I have experience with big data, and I want to prove whether MySQL on single node computer can't process the big data faster. I run an query like this

```
SELECT   b.nama, COUNT(a.id) 
FROM     transaksi a, member b 
WHERE    a.idmember = b.id
GROUP BY b.nama
```

So, I want to know the relationship between join process, query time, and the number of rows. If I multiply and add the number of rows on a table, can this make query slower?

Comment: Did you do any research about this topic before asking your question?

Comment: I'm already search for this issue but I don't get the proper answer yet, and because this issue relating to my assignment about big data processing, so I asked here....

Comment: Don't you want to add `GROUP BY b.nama`?

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to write it....

Comment: If you are regularly running queries that iterate over your entire dataset and produce a summarised result then you are probably storing your data in the wrong structure.

Answer (score 0):

Queries on large amounts of data are limited to disk I/O speed with one sequential pass over the data.

It is certainly possible to craft a benchmark that works at full speed in one program, but will work in some less efficient way in another program.

A `JOIN` is an example of where "Relational Databases" tend to have an advantage over brute force techniques that often exist in non-SQL programs.  But, if I read you correctly, that is the opposite of what you want to prove?

Comment: what do you mean about the opposite that I want to prove?

Comment: Maybe I misread your question?  Are you trying to "prove" that MySQL is slower?   or faster?

Comment: yes, you're right actually I want to prove mysql query slower than hadoop mapreduce program that I made. But I want to know, the query condition that make it slower.... Thanks